# looking for a singleboard computer for a wireless usb hub (low power consumption,ultra compact, multi-usb host)

Tags: wireless, embedded-systems

I am looking for a very compact single board computer(SBC), that has at least two usb hosts, a low power consumption and ideally a thin form factor.

I want to run to make a usb2.0 scientific camera wireless using a virtual usb client (https://www.virtualhere.com) which will compress (LZ4) and transmit the information via wifi. I have measured the usb data rate, it is about 23.5 megabytes/second. Thus, a wifi-ac dongle, connected to the SBC should be adequate for this purpose. Since I do not want the camera to share the USB host with the wifi dongle, I will need at least two usb hosts. Since the whole unit will be powered by a lion phone battery (with a voltage converter to 5V), ideally I am looking for a low power consumption.

Since the SBC will be mounted on the back of the camera, I would like a board with a thin form factor.... although I guess I can de-solder some of the connectors.

If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated. 
I should add that I am already aware of the Khadas VIM.
 Also I have looked at SBCs with Allwinner system on-chip H3 and H5 variants e.g the banana pi, orange pi and nano pi.... but I am not sure which have lower power consumption.

Comment: Why do you not want them to share a USB host? There are plenty of computers that can handle that data rate on a single host.

Comment: I am assuming here that the combined camera + wifi dongle usb data rates  may exceed the capacity of a single usb host.

Comment: I can't speak for every board ever, but I believe the Joule 570X should have a throughput of 500Mb/s. Not recommending you buy that board by any means, but a single controller should be fine.